# Don't want to fun function if parameters are entered on the command line

Tags: linux, bash, function, command-line

I've been looking around but can't find a solution...

Basically, I have a program that creates user accounts, and I can also create an account using the command line interface.
What I want, is when I use the command line, the rest of the program doesn't run. Because at the moment, it creates the account, then returns to the menu.

```
function menu {
  echo "Welcome to OP-SYS Account creation. Please choose which mode you would like to continue in."
  echo

  echo "[1] Basic Account Creation"
  echo "[2] Advanced Account Creation"
  echo "[3] Exit"
  echo

#Change user input to functions, reject others
  read CHOICE #Load user input to variable
    if  [ "$CHOICE" = 1 ] || [ "$CHOICE" = 2 ] || [ "$CHOICE" = 3 ]; then
#Goto function opt#
      opt"$CHOICE"
    else
      echo "That is not a valid entry. Returning you to the menu."
      sleep 2
      clear
      menu
    fi

}

#other code#  

    konsoleend() {
    clear
    #popd
    }

username=$1
firstname=$2
surname=$3
password=$4
    echo "$firstname" "$surname" >> "$username".log
    echo "$password" >> "$username".log
    curdate=$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    echo "$curdate" >> "$username".log
    #menu
    konsoleend
    menu
```

Comment: Use an infinite loop: wrap your `read` and `if` block with a `while :; do` and `done` block. You can break the loop with either the `break` builtin or the `return` builtin (the latter returns from the function).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Making a distinction between a "program" and a  "command line interface"  is a bit odd.  Perhaps you mean you have a program that can be run interactively or non-interactively, or you want to distinguish between a gui and a cli.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what you mean by the distinction between a 
"command line interface" and a "program", but perhaps you simply mean that if no arguments are given to the program you want to use the menu.  If that is the case, simply write:

```
test $# = 0 && menu
```

in the last line of the script rather than just `menu`

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed, but the test needs to check that there are all 4 parameters, rather than just not being null

Comment: `test $# = 4 || menu`, then, but I suspect you also want to validate the arguments.  If not, you should want that.  Better yet, write one program that takes arguments, and a completely different program that presents the menu and invokes the first.  Separate your ui from the functionality.

Comment: I can only have one script right now. Also, I cannot seem to get this right... I've redone your code to make it so if there are 4 params, then create account, if not tell the user it didn't work - THESE ARE ON THE COMMAND LINE; But if I run the normal code BY EXECUTING THE PROGRAM, it just says there are not enough params. Is that making sense? :/

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.  "if I run the normal code BY EXECUTING THE PROGRAM" makes no sense at all.  How else would you run the normal code unless you execute the program?

Comment: Apologies. I can run it via `./OPSYS.sh` and it will give me a menu that I can input the account into. BUT what I also want, if when I do `./OPSYS.sh Username First Last password` it will create an account without pulling up the menu, and then close the program.

Comment: It sounds like somewhere in 'other code' there is a check that aborts if the user doesn't supply 4 arguments.

Comment: There is only code that checks if the arguments exist, but they're different to this part of the code